# Xamarin Forms SQLite Update

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, insert-update

I have installed the nuget package [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) and I want to insert or update depending on the text on the button:

```
 SQLiteConnection database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
 database.CreateTable<Announcement>(); 
 var announcement = new Announcement { AnnouncementTitle = Title, AnnouncementDate = Date, AnnouncementText = Message };
 if (text == "Save") {
     if (database.Insert(announcement) != -1) {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INSERTED");
     }

 }
 else {
    if (database.Update(announcement) > 0) {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UPDATED");
    }
 }
```

When I want to save it print INSERTED and I can see the new item in my list but when it comes to update it doesn't print anything and I don't get an error. I also tried the async methods and it didn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to update you have to get the original entry from the database first. Now you don't have the `Id` field (or how it is called in your model) entered, so it doesn't know what to update.

Update your code to do something like this, note: this is pseudo code since I am missing some details of your model and relevant knowledge of SQLite.

```
 SQLiteConnection database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
 database.CreateTable<Announcement>(); 
 var announcement = new Announcement { AnnouncementTitle = Title, AnnouncementDate = Date, AnnouncementText = Message };
 if (text == "Save") {
     if (database.Insert(announcement) != -1) {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INSERTED");
     }

 }
 else {
    var announcementToUpdate = database.Query<Customer>($"SELECT * FROM Announcement WHERE Id = '{originalId}'").

    // update your 'announcementToUpdate' object with new values here

    if (database.Update(announcementToUpdate) > 0) {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UPDATED");
    }
 }
```

`originalId` should be a variable with the announcement of the Id you're trying to edit.

So the key here to update is that you have to retrieve the record from the database first. *Or* create a new object with the `Id` of the record that you want updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get this error: System.NotSupportedException: Cannot update List`1: it has no PK, I as trying to delete the announcement havinh id = 1:    var announcementToUpdate = database.Query<Announcement>($"SELECT * FROM Announcement WHERE AnnouncementId = '{1}'");

Comment: So your model doesn't have a Primary Key. I recommend you specify one. Read about it in the docs [here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net)

Comment: yes it has: [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }

Comment: But you're now trying to delete something? Maybe you should remove the app from your simulator/device to clear the database, there is now some old entries in there which might cause trouble now.

Comment: It worked :) it prints UPDATED but it didn't update it :( . I uninstalled the app  and change this: database.Update(announcementToUpdate[0]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126785/discussion-between-mireille-and-gerald-versluis).

Answer (score 4):

you need a primary Key or Id in your object Announcement like

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

to identify your unique object in your database.

In your code you always create a new object with no id. SQLite see it an create a new Id in the database for your. But if the Id ist empty the update not work.

If you want to update it you must load it from the database with the correct Id, then you can edit and update it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have an Id in my table and I will try to get it